# unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (not version related?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, selenium-webdriver, capybara, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I just installed `selenium-webdriver` (2.45.0) to use with `capybara` (2.4.0) for feature testing (version from `bundle show`).  I removed the version number from my `gemfile` for these two to ensure I am getting the latest versions.  When I got this error, I searched SO and subsequently downgraded `Firefox` to version 33.

I have read through all of the "unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds" posts on SO and the theme is generally the same - the version of `selenium-webdriver` does not work with the latest version of `Firefox`.  Unfortunately, I have tried everything suggested and still get the same error.

Is there some other (very basic) thing I may be missing (bearing in mind that I just started with selenium)?  Note also that I am using the Cloud9 IDE.

**UPDATE** - my test environment settings (comments removed for brevity):

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = false
  config.serve_static_files  = true
  config.static_cache_control = 'public, max-age=3600'
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.active_support.test_order = :random
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem couples of months ago and I solved this by download a stable version of firefox, placed it to my local directory then
in --/featutes/support/env.rb file i set the path of Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path

Here is my code:
..............

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=("/localpath/firefox/firefox") if REGISTRY[:local_path_for_selenium] # I have used condition so it will not effect my production enviroment
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = false
  profile.secure_ssl = false
  http_client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  http_client.timeout = 410
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :profile => profile,:http_client => http_client)
end
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

.............

Comment: Thanks Raza.  Not sure what you mean by "placed FF in a local directory"... couldn't I just set path to wherever it is currently downloaded (V33)?  Also where is `/features/support/env.rb`?  Do you mean `config/environments/test.rb'?  Lastly, wouldn't `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium` cause Capybara to use Selenium for all of my feature tests (not just ones with JS)?

Comment: 1. downloaded(V33) extract in you file system(anywere) if it is gz file
2 Don't worry about 'features/support/env.rb' basically cucmber setting files, It may vary. 
3. Last thing you have to do is SET Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=("/localpath/firefox/firefox")
path of your downloaded FF.  End of story

Comment: Search in you app "Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::" the set its binary path to  local FF binary.

Comment: OK thanks Raza.  I am in the middle of something else but it is on my list to try later.  I'll let you know how I make out.

Comment: vote up if it is useful and it it works then please accept my answer

Comment: I can't find Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox or anything like it in my project.  I'm wondering if this is just a `Cucumber` thing.

Comment: try add the above code in  "config/environments/test.rb" or share some tell me more about your test env settings

Comment: worked for me i have changed path `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=("/localpath/firefox/firefox") if REGISTRY[:local_path_for_selenium]` to my FF path i-e `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=("/usr/bin/firefox")`

Comment: Don't forget to set REGISTRY[:local_path_for_selenium] = true